# "Too many positionals passed" in NativeCall sub binding

Tags: raku, nativecall

I have this defined:

```
use NativeCall;

unit module kazmath;

class mat4 is repr('CStruct') {
    HAS num32 @.mat[16] is CArray;
}

sub kmMat4Fill( mat4 $mat, num32 @filler ) returns mat4 is native('kazmath')
                                            is export {*}
```

The  function to bind is [defined here](https://github.com/Kazade/kazmath/blob/master/kazmath/mat4.h#L60):

```
kmMat4* kmMat4Fill(kmMat4* pOut, const kmScalar* pMat);
```

And the error returned is:

```
Too many positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 3
```

I really can't figure this out.

Comment: It might be related to the `extern "C" { }` declaration in `math4.h`. Maybe raku is passing an implicit  `this` argument which is not  expected?

Comment: @HåkonHægland. It might, but that happens only if it's compiled with c++. I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed with

```
sub kmMat4Fill( mat4 $mat, CArray[num32] $filler )
        returns mat4 is native('kazmath') is export {*}
```

Positionals can't be used in NativeCall, but still, the error message is LTA (Less Than Awesome).

Comment: With  to all... I primarily associate `LTA` with an empathetic notion that speaks to both end users and implementors, an up-lifting *aspirational* connotation that some error messages are weak, even very weak, and need improvement, perhaps a lot. Sort of `LTA eqv Larry.Thinks.Aspirationally`. But part of the point of `@Larry`'s memes is artistic flexibility, and I find it fun to: remember what I've forgotten about a meme; discover meanings I didn't know; invent new ones; or share ones I think might apply in a particular scenario. In that vein: `LTA eqv Ludicrously.Tormentingly.Abstruse`. 